# Examining covariance between biodiversity and other variables

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, geostatistical-analyst

I want to examine the **covariance between ecosystem services** in an area. I don´t really know if covariance is the correct word, however.

I have identified and combined different variables indicating high biodiversity using the weighted overlay and graded the areas from 1-10, whereas 10 is indicating high biodiversity.

Now I want to investigate how the biodiversity covariates/coexists/relates (english isn´t my native language) with other variables.

The other variables could be biotopes, soil type or other ecosystem services, like recreation.

My data consists of:

- polygons with the graded biodiversity and also the same areas in a raster.
- polygons indicating biotopes, soil type, precipitation etc.
- polygons indicating whether an area is used for a certain activity like mushrooming and so on.

The polygons are divided into green spaces at a county level.

So, what I want to do is to se if there are any hot spots where biodiversity are more likely to coexist with an other variable. I would like to visualize it on a map but also get a diagram over the relationships.

How do I do that?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Spatial Statistics toolbox. There are a few tools in there that might be good candidates for what you want to accomplish (Geographically Weighted Regression maybe?).

I'm not sure the best way to handle the biotope, soil typed, etc. variables though, as they aren't really numeric values. You might be able to do something like union the variable data with the biodiversity data. Perform the analysis on that and use your 1-10 biodiversity values as a weight.  You'd need to do that separately for each variable layer.